# Calculate if sum() is between range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently working on some cricket data, where I need to find the strike rate (runs*100/balls) of a batsman between a range of scores.

I have a ranges table like this:

```
| lower | upper   |
| ------| ------- |
| 0     | 10      |
| 10    | 20      |
| 20    | 30      |
| 30    | 40      |
| 40    | 50      |
| 50    | 60      |
| 60    | NULL    |
```

I also have a table with ball-by-ball data, which shows how many runs are scored by a batsman in every ball:

```
| inning  | ball  | runs    |  striker | non_striker|
| ------  | ------| ------- | -------  | ---------- |
| 1       | 1     | 0       |   1      |    2       |
| 1       | 2     | 4       |   1      |    2       |
| 1       | 3     | 0       |   1      |    2       |
| 1       | 4     | 1       |   1      |    2       |
| 1       | 5     | 1       |   2      |    1       |
| 1       | 6     | 0       |   1      |    2       |
```

I've figured out how to get their scores for the entire match:

```
select striker, sum(runs) as "runs", count(*) as "balls", sum(runs)*100/count(*) as "strike_rate"
from balls
group by inning, striker
```

How would I get them when the batsman scores are between the individual ranges?

The expected output would be something like:

```
| batsman| end_score   | end_balls  |score_at_10| score_at_20|
| ------ | ----------  | ---------- | --------- | ---------  |
| 1      |     52      |     31     |     15    |    32      |
| 2      |     22      |     16     |     14    |    NULL    |
```

Where end would be the final score they achieved before getting out, or the innings ending (basically sum(runs) and count(*))

Comment: What is the exact output you want to see here?

Comment: Is upper really lower than lower? Has the ranges table a name or id column to display?

Comment: Is "upper" supposed to be lower than "lower"? What's "striker_id"? Did you mean "striker" or is your table heading wrong? Please go over you question and make sure everything is correct.

Comment: I see no column `batsman_scored` in `balls`.

Comment: Should the query contain `sum(runs) as batsman_scored`?

Comment: Please explain "end_balls" and "end_score". Where is "end" found in the data?

Comment: What data determines the order of the balls? (i.e. to get "the first 10" or the first 20? we need something to order by) **Do you have the "over" number in the data?** or are you assuming the the rows are stored in the wanted order. If that is the assumption problem is tables are "unordered sets" so you still need something to explicitly determine the order when performing calculations.